# Brownie Errors when attempting to compile

Tags: ethereum, web3py, brownie

When I type "brownie compile" it doesn't work and I get this error. Anybody know why?

```
  File "c:\users\sircr\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "c:\users\sircr\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\compile.py", line 50, in main
    proj = project.load()
  File "c:\users\sircr\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 750, in load
    return Project(name, project_path)
  File "c:\users\sircr\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 182, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "c:\users\sircr\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 237, in load
    self._compile(changed, self._compiler_config, False)
  File "c:\users\sircr\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 89, in _compile
    _install_dependencies(self._path)
  File "c:\users\sircr\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 756, in _install_dependencies
    install_package(package_id)
  File "c:\users\sircr\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 778, in install_package
    return _install_from_github(package_id)
  File "c:\users\sircr\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 851, in _install_from_github
    raise ConnectionError(msg)
ConnectionError: Status 404 when getting package versions from Github: 'Not Found'
```

Comment: Anyone got any advice how to debug this error?

For me it works for OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0

but not for smartcontractkid/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2

can't figure out why. Frustrating!

Comment: UPDATE: when I used smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1 it worked fine.   Maybe check your dependencies and whether the version is okay.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, Even tried with version 1.1.1. Were you able to overcome this issue? thanks in advance

Comment: Add your `brownie-config` to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your config file, it mostly gives an error due to typos. in my file i had written the dependency right after the hyphen(-) without any space and when i fixed it the contract was compiled properly

brownie-config.yaml file *before* solving the error

```
dependencies:
  -smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
```

brownie-config.yaml file *after* solving the error

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
```

do the same whenever using an hyphen(-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't written the right link and also, when you paste the import for the V3 aggregator check the version, I changed V0.8 to V0.6 to be correct with the solidity version 0.6.6

ex:  for me, I just added a s at contract to solve the issue.
smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1 is ok instead of smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contract@1.1.1 I've written at first (wrongly)

after those changes, it worked perfectly